# Google Places Autocomplete Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-places-api

I am trying to implement Google Places Autocomplete in Vue.js.

The [API states that](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Autocomplete) the `Autocomplete` class first takes an `inputField:HTMLInputElement`, as used in their example:

```
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
    {types: ['geocode']});
```

Since we cannot pass elements around by their ID's in Vue.js? How would this be achieved, and what kind of construct would we pass?

e.g. the following code fails

```
<template>
  <input id="autocomplete" placeholder="Enter your address" type="text"></input>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    created() {
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(document.getElementById('autocomplete')),
    {types: ['geocode']});
    }
  }
</script>
```

with error:

```
InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement
```

Comment: Use [ref](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref)

Comment: @MathewJibin thank you.

Comment: I have followed your code.I m getting auto populated google auto complete.How to get the selected address, state and country from your code ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok so following Matthew Jibin's suggestion to use `ref`, I got it to show up. Lots more to do but initial hurdle overcome.

```
<template>
  <input ref="autocomplete" 
         placeholder="Enter your address" 
         type="text"
  />
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    mounted() {
      var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      /** @type {!HTMLInputElement} */(this.$refs.autocomplete),
      {types: ['geocode']});
    }
  }
</script>
```

One addition, from the docs:

> An important note about the ref registration timing: because the refs
>   themselves are created as a result of the render function, you cannot
>   access them on the initial render - they don’t exist yet!

So the `created()` hook isn't the right one. `mounted()` is what we're looking for.

Comment: This seems to get the div that encloses the input field, not the input itself.

Comment: @softcode I have followed your code.I m getting auto populated google auto complete.How to get the selected address, state and country from your code ?

Comment: @BhoomiBhalani (1) Move autocomplete to component`data()`, (2) Add event listener to autocomplete after creating it: 
`this.autocompleteInput.addListener('place_changed', yourNewMethod());` and (3) Declare `yourNewMethod`