# How to use google places autocomplete in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I have my google places autocomplete in my vue `app.vue` however I get the error 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setBounds' of undefined
    at eval`
[image: Vue Error]

This is my code https://hastebin.com/ebogewehir.vue

From the `console.logs` it appears that `console.log(autocomplete.getPlace())` prints `undefined` but `console.log(autocomplete)` prints `Bx`.

I followed the documentation from google here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

I used the `ref` variable from here [Google Places Autocomplete Vue.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41688977/google-places-autocomplete-vue-js)

Comment: First of all remove redundant inclusions of google API. It must be included to the page only once to prevent uncontrolled иурфмшщк

Comment: But im not actually loading any other google api. most of them are part of key - value fields in json. As below
`"auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
    "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk-9tvm6%40my-new-project-11447.iam.gserviceaccount.com"`

Are these counted as invoking the same api? 

The main api that I have in script tag is 
` <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXXX&libraries=places"></script>`
Thats the only one in script tag